# ScriptStatementFailedException in sql file

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'm having *org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException* from a sql script i'm using with h2 in a spring project.

```
SET @TEASER = '<p> Text Text Text</p>'
SET @BODY = '<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>'

insert into author(id,first_name,last_name,email) values(1,'Dan','Vega','DVega@gmail.com');
insert into post(id,title,slug,teaser,body,author_id,posted_on) values(1,'Spring boot rocks','spring-boot-rocks',@TEASER,@BODY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into post(id,title,slug,teaser,body,author_id,posted_on) values(2,'Spring boot is kew;','spring-boot-is-kewl',@TEASER,@BODY,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

This is the Post class i'm using

```
@Entity
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String title;
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String body;
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String teaser;
private String slug;
@CreatedDate @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private Date postedOn;
@ManyToOne
private Author author;
// constructors, getters and setters
```

error - it's repeated for every class it has anything to do with the Post class, in this case HomeController has a PostService class autowired which has a PostRepository autowired attribute.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPostService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPostRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3f6f9cef' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3f6f9cef': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Talon/Desktop/java%20netbeans/01/SpringBootH2Demo/target/classes/data-h2.sql]: SET @TEASER = '<p> Text Text Text</p>' SET @BODY = '<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>' insert into author(id,first_name,last_name,email) values(1,'Dan','Vega','DVega@gmail.com'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SET @TEASER = '<p> Text Text Text</p>' SET[*] @BODY = '<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>' INSERT INTO AUTHOR(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL) VALUES(1,'Dan','Vega','DVega@gmail.com') "; SQL statement:
SET @TEASER = '<p> Text Text Text</p>' SET @BODY = '<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>' insert into author(id,first_name,last_name,email) values(1,'Dan','Vega','DVega@gmail.com') [42000-196]
```

If i remove the @TEASER and @BODY from the sql file, and from the post values insertion it works. So did i misspell something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have forgot to put the semicolon after SET statement.

SET @TEASER = 'Text Text Text';
SET @BODY = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
Try this, if works